# I got an error "You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP."

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, debian-buster

I am using CakePHP 4, apache2.4, PHP8.0 and OS is Debian.

I already uncommented `extension=intl in php.ini` then I found another intl.ini in different directory and it's also uncommented so I ran `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and check  then `php -v`this error came => Module "intl" is already loaded. So I commented one of them. Then error is gone but I still getting the error "enable intl" one.

I've been struggling this for days.

Comment: Usually there are two different php.ini's. One for CLI (which is what's used when you run `php -v`) and then one for Apache. Make sure you're changing the correct one. Make a PHP page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and visit it through your web server with your browser and see if you see intl there.

Comment: I went to PHP page and I found intl `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/conf.d/20-intl.ini` in Additional.ini files parsed section.  But when I scroll down the web, at the intl section, `intl.default_locale` shows no value

Comment: It fixed after I uninstalled all php file and started fresh which I didn't want to but Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

With Debian it's not enough just to uncomment the line in PHP.INI as you won't have the `intl` software available.

You need to install the `intl` package, which will update the PHP.INI files as well.

At the command line enter

```
sudo apt install php8.0-intl
```

Then restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And if you're using the FPM module, restart that too

```
sudo service php8.0-fpm restart
```

Comment: Yeah, I did run `sudo apt install php8.0-intl` but it says like I already downloaded the lastest version

Comment: It fixed after I uninstalled all php file and started fresh which I didn't want to but Thank you so much!!